# How to hide objects after deletion in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

in my Django admin interface if I delete something it leads to default Django admin deletion page. In that page under objects category can we delete any object message or make changes in it? I have provided with the image!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should override Django admin `delete_selected_confirmation.html` template ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_selected_confirmation.html)) by following [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)